# read string out of stream

Tags: string, stream, buffer, streamreader

I got a problem when reading a stream into a string.. This is my code (comments behind Debug.Log is the result I get..)

```
public static string ToString(MemoryStream stream)
{
Debug.Log (stream.Position + " / " + stream.Length); // 1449 / 1449
stream.Position = 0;
Debug.Log (stream.Position) // 0
Debug.Log (stream.CanRead); // true
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
Debug.Log ("Reader basestream length: " + reader.BaseStream.Length); //Reader basestream length: 1449
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
char[] buffer = new char[stream.Length];
int charCount = reader.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
string anotherTry = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
Debug.Log (anotherTry); // empty string
Debug.Log (text); // empty string
Debug.Log ("Buffer: " + buffer.Length + ";   charCount: " + charCount); // Buffer: 1449;   charCount: 0
return(text);
}
```

Can anyone show me what i'm doing wrong? Can't figure out any other possible problem with this..
The stream should contain savedatas from my game using a BinaryFormatter..
I use the same version to store savedata in a file in the desktop version of the game and there I get a file with data inside.. So the stream can't be empty..

Comment: Can't see that you've done anything wrong, what is stream an instance of? FileStream, MemoryStream etc.

Comment: Was just a Stream but now I changed to MemoryStream.. Same problem..
string anotherTry = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray()); doesnt work too...

Comment: If you used a BinaryFormatter to serialize your data, why are you reading it as a string ?

Comment: Just a stream, not possible, Stream is an abstract class, so must have been passing in one of it's descendants

Comment: I guess it's a filestream but in my script it is just was "public static string ToString(Stream stream)".
That i meant with just a Stream..

Comment: I checked the file which is created in the standalone version.. the "text" inside is mostly C0 control code. (Like "NUL" with a black background, than "SOH" with a black background, three more "NUL")... May that be the reason I can't convert it to a string? There is also normal text in it (e.g. "Assembly-CSharp")..